# iOS Facebook SSO for Air app and web service authentication

Tags: ios, web-services, authentication, air, single-sign-on

we are developing an iOS App using Adobe Flex/Air. The app uses a web service that needs user authentication via facebook login. At the moment, we use server side authentication: There's a login URL displayed in a WebView where the facebook login is done. This way, we get an access_token that can be used on the server side.

This works perfectly but it would really be much better if we could use Single Sign-on with the facebook ios app. As far as I have read, this should work on the client side but I haven't found a way to authenticate the user on the server side.

facebook's access_tokens are valid either for use on the server-side or for the client side so an access_token from the client-side login won't work for the server side.

Thanks in advance for your ideas,

Henk

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't want to provide SSO client-side using the Facebook iOS SDK, and then just pass a token to your server saying that user "X" has logged in, thereby starting a session?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you're making this far more complicated than it's really intended to be.  Leverage the Facebook iOS SDK, and all of the heavy lifting involved with authenticating the user within your app is handled by the Facebook SDK. There's no need to independently provide sign-in sheets and manage access token exchange between the app's local storage and Facebook's servers without the convenience of the *entire* Facebook SDK.

This link shows you how to implement SSO natively within your iOS app. It's real simple.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso

Then, I understand that you're keeping authentication information or central user database information on an external server. The best way to **synchronize** the information between the FB client and your own servers is to simply check the login information returned by the FB SDK with your server after you receive it.

Here's a simple breakdown:

1. Log the user in using Facebook's standard SDK (see the link above).
2. In the `-didLogin` method (or whatever the equivalent is in your Adobe AIR environment), check the access token returned by FB with your server. Not sure what server architecture you're using, but it's safe to say that this will go on outside of the FB SDK. Also, save the access token in your app's user defaults so that the user won't have to login again next time. This whole process should (and inherently will) feel much quicker than it sounds.
3. If the check with the server returns successfully, notify the user of a successful login. If not, display an error view explaining the reason the user was rejected/not logged in.

Why do it this way? The reason is fairly simple. It's safe to assume that the reason you're having a user login to your app via Facebook is so that you can make requests for the user's Facebook information (i.e. feeds, photos, likes, comments, etc.). The easiest (and best) way to do this is through the FB SDK its self. The SDK takes care of a lot of stuff behind the scenes like access token validation over time, extension of token life, validity of token, and so on. This way, you won't have to worry nearly as much about syncronizing the server information and real-time client information when changes take place. Just authenticate via the FB iOS SDK, and do the rest of your own processing afterward.

Comment below if there's anything I should clarify or even if I missed the point of your question entirely--I tend to get on a roll and may stray from the point. :)

Cheers!
The Kraken